Debezium-Oracle-Connector : Exception: Failed to resolve Oracle database version
Configuration:

Oracle for windows is installed locally
Running Kafka Connect through docker

  connect:
    image: debezium/connect-with-oracle-jdbc:2.6

oracle kafka connect configuration:
{
  "name": "inventory-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
    "topic.prefix" : "server1",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "database.server.name" : "XEPDB1",
    "database.hostname" : "localhost",
    "database.port" : "1521",
    "database.user" : "DBZUSER",
    "database.password" : "oracle",
    "database.dbname" : "XEPDB1",
    "database.pdb.name" : "XEPDB1",
    "database.connection.adapter" : "logminer",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
    "database.oracle.version": "12+",

    "transforms": "route",

    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$3",

    "table.include.list": "DBZUSER\\.CUSTOMERS",
    "column.include.list": "DBZUSER\\.CUSTOMERS\\.(ID|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME)"
  }
}

getting following exception:
2024-05-23 23:35:03 2024-05-23 18:05:03,519 ERROR  ||  Failed testing connection for {connector.class=io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector, database.user=DBZUSER, database.dbname=XEPDB1, tasks.max=1, database.pdb.name=XEPDB1, database.connection.adapter=logminer, database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092, database.history.kafka.topic=schema-changes.inventory, transforms=route, database.server.name=XEPDB1, column.include.list=DBZUSER\.CUSTOMERS\.(ID|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME), database.port=1521, transforms.route.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter, topic.prefix=server1, transforms.route.regex=([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+), database.hostname=localhost, database.password=********, name=inventory-connector, database.oracle.version=12+, table.include.list=DBZUSER\.CUSTOMERS, transforms.route.replacement=$3} with user '[database.user,null,[],[],true]'   [io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector]
2024-05-23 23:35:03 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: Failed to resolve Oracle database version
2024-05-23 23:35:03     at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.resolveOracleDatabaseVersion(OracleConnection.java:201)
2024-05-23 23:35:03     at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:110)
2024-05-23 23:35:03     at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:91)
2024-05-23 23:35:03     at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector.validateConnection(OracleConnector.java:78)
2024-05-23 23:35:03     at io.debezium.connector.common.RelationalBaseSourceConnector.validate(RelationalBaseSourceConnector.java:42)


Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You should recheck information about Oracle Connection which includes: serrvicename/sid. and its IP Address. If you run Oracle under docker, you should expose the DB port and in database.hostname you should set the value to your server IP instead of localhost.

The oracle is installed locally. Through sql-developer I am able to connect to the database using localhost and port 1521.. but because of some reason kafka connect is not able to connect to the oracle db and throws.. Failed to resolve Oracle database version

Failed to resolve Oracle database version
This is a very generic exception and does not specify the real cause

When you register new connector configuration through calling Connector's API. Docker connect container tooks 'localhost' as connector itself, not your physical host. Did you try replace it with your physx IP ?.
